# How to run ScalaApplication in Docker Container by Gradle?

Tags: scala, docker, gradle

I have found next gradle task, for javaApplication:

```
group 'habrServer'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.docker-java-application'
apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.docker-remote-api'

import com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.tasks.container.DockerCreateContainer

mainClassName = 'ru.test.HabrWebServer'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-docker-plugin:3.0.3'
    }
}

docker {
    url = 'http://127.0.0.1:2375'
    javaApplication {
        maintainer = 'Dmitry Barkalov "xxx@xxx.xxx"'
        ports = [8080]
        tag = 'habrwebserver'
    }
}

task createDocker(type: DockerCreateContainer) {
    dependsOn dockerBuildImage
    targetImageId { dockerBuildImage.getImageId() }
    portBindings = ['8080:8080']
}


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile group: 'org.glassfish.grizzly', name: 'grizzly-http-server', version: '2.3.28'
}
```

But I need run ScalaApplication  in docker container, how can I  do this? Maybe there are plugins for connect gradle + scala +docker?

P.S.
I can't guide in Internet. Thanks.

Comment: From Docker's point of view there is no difference between Java, Scala, Clojure etc. All you need to do is to package your app in a JAR archive, maybe add main class to manifest.mf to be able to run your app with `java -jar ...`. Then put this archive into a docker image and that's all.